# Change the mouse pointer in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a frame in html using the

```
<frame></frame>
```

tags.
Is there a way i can change the mouse pointer as the mouse enters the frame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You may find here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

This is the css for cursor.

Try to:

```
<frame style="cursor:auto"></frame>
```

instead of `auto` you can use anyone of the following:

```
auto    Default. The browser sets a cursor
crosshair   The cursor render as a crosshair
default The default cursor
e-resize    The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved right (east)
help    The cursor indicates that help is available
move    The cursor indicates something that should be moved
n-resize    The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved up (north)
ne-resize   The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved up and right (north/east)
nw-resize   The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved up and left (north/west)
pointer The cursor render as a pointer
progress    The cursor indicates that the program is busy (in progress)
s-resize    The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved down (south)
se-resize   The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved down and right (south/east)
sw-resize   The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved down and left (south/west)
text    The cursor indicates text
w-resize    The cursor indicates that an edge of a box is to be moved left (west)
wait    The cursor indicates that the program is busy
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [cursor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) CSS property

```
<style>
.mousePointer
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<frame class="mousePointer"></frame>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is the css cursor property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp
You can also do: `cursor:url(/mousePointer.cur)`

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS:

```
.myClass { cursor: pointer; }
#myId { cursor: pointer; }
```

Or an entrie element(s)s:

```
frame { cursor: pointer; }
p { cursor: pointer; }
```

Also you can try with Inline-CSS:

Or something like this:

```
<div id="clickMe" onclick="alert('I\'m clicked!'); return false;" style="cursor: pointer;">I'm a Fake-Link!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this : - 

**HTML**

```
  <iframe class="pointer"></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
   .pointer
          {
            cursor: pointer;
          }
```

the other options of changing cursors are : -

```
 auto
 crosshair
 default
 e-resize
 help
 move
 n-resize
 ne-resize
 nw-resize
 pointer
 progress
 s-resize
 se-resize
 sw-resize
 text
 w-resize
 wait
```